# Unable to Access Symantec Endpoint Protection API on Port 8446

Tags: symantec

I have installed a trial Version of Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager.
It is installed successfully and I am able to access it from the Client and from the Web UI.

**But I am not able to access the API on Port 8446.**

Does Symantec provide access to API in trial version ?
If yes, is there a way to activate/enable it ?

Answer (score -1):

No you cannot access API of SEPM..
It has REST API Documents for developer that interact with Symantec™ Endpoint Protection Manager REST API Reference.